# Redirect Emails with qmail to a ruby script

Tags: ruby, qmail

as the topic says, I want to redirect an incoming mail to a rubyscript. I know i can pass the mail via |path/to/script to a script, but i have no idea how to work with the input in ruby...

Hope someone could show me the right direction.

thanks

Comment: rails or just plain ruby ?

Comment: This question is off topic, because it doesn't relate to *code* or *programming* directly. You may want to ask over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/), and when you do, make sure you specify what e-mail server, and environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mail gem (https://github.com/mikel/mail)  to read emails.  Just grab it from stdin, and then pass it in.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'mail'

 message = $stdin.read 
 mail = Mail.new(message)

 ... work with the Mail here ..
```

The documentation on the github is pretty good.